# How to find the found word in the dictionary?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create a dictionary that stores words and their definitions.

So far, I've done basic things like creating structures and empty dictionary struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct{

   char wordInDictionary[32];
   int numberOfMeanings;
   char *wordDefinitions[10];

}Entry; //describes one entry in the dictionary

typedef struct{

   int entries;
   Entry *arrayOfEntries[100];

}Dictionary; //whole dictionary

Dictionary createDictionary(){

   Dictionary emptyDictionary;

   emptyDictionary.entries = 0;

   int i,j;

   for(i=0;i<100;i++){
       emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i] = (Entry*)malloc(sizeof(Entry*));
       emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->numberOfMeanings = 0;
       strcpy(emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->wordInDictionary, "hello"); //assigning "hello" string because want to test another function in main
       for(j=0;j<10;j++){
           emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->wordDefinitions[j] = 
           (char*)malloc(500*sizeof(char*));

           strcpy(emptyDictionary.arrayOfEntries[i]->wordDefinitions[j], "\0");
       }
   }

   return emptyDictionary;

}
```

Then there is a function of a type that points to Entry which searches for some given **word**, it looks as follows:

```
Entry *searchWord(char word[], Dictionary *dict){

   Entry *foundWord;

   int i;

   for(i=0;i<100;i++){
       if(dict->arrayOfEntries[i]->wordInDictionary != word){
           foundWord = NULL;
       }else{
           foundWord = dict->arrayOfEntries[i];
       }
    }

   return foundWord;

}
```

So **searchWord()** should return a pointer to entry if word is found, if not it just return NULL pointer. Then I tested everything in **main()** but it seems like **searchWord()** does not work as it is supposed to:

```
int main(){


   Entry* newEntry;

   Dictionary dict = createDictionary();

   char word[] = "hello";
   newEntry = searchWord(word, &dict);

   if (newEntry != NULL) {
       printf("\nWord found: '%s'", word);
   } else {
       printf("\nWord '%s' is not found in the dictionary.", word);
   }

   return 0;

}
```

Even though in my empty dictionary I made every word to be "hello", in console the program output: *Word 'hello' is not found in the dictionary.* Where the possible issue could be?

Comment: You probably want a `break;` statement in the `else` branch of `searchWord`

Comment: In `searchWord`, you compare the strings with `==`, which compares their addresses. You want `strcmp` instead, which compares the strings' contents.

Comment: Aside in `Dictionary createDictionary()` it seems a bit much to return that giant `struct`. It is legal, but is more usual to either pass a pointer to the function, or allocate memory there and return a pointer.

Comment: If you're going to `malloc()` 100 `Entry` structures all the time, you might as well make it an array of structures instead of an array of pointers to structures. Saves a lot of allocations and makes the code *way* simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
if(dict->arrayOfEntries[i]->wordInDictionary != word){
           foundWord = NULL;
```

If you want to compare string, you should use `strcmp`:

```
if(strcmp(dict->arrayOfEntries[i]->wordInDictionary, word) != 0){
           foundWord = NULL;
```